# Trouble with VBA designed to prevent cells with values from being edited upon save

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a table in a spreadsheet that multiple users will be editing.  We have had problems with people pasting over other entries accidentally or moving half of a row up several columns.  I want to protect every cell with values in it, or alternatively allow every cell without values to be edited.

I have tried making the whole table editable, then locking the cells with values in it.  This seemed to do nothing, as I was able to edit values anyway.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NewEditRange As Range
    Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataTable As Range
    Dim CurrentEditRange As AllowEditRange
    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    Set ThisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set DataTable = ThisSheet.Range("Table1")
    Set NewEditRange = ThisSheet.Range("$A$1")
    ThisSheet.Unprotect
    For Each CurrentEditRange In ThisSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges
        CurrentEditRange.Delete
    Next
    For Each CurrentCell In DataTable
        If CurrentCell.Value = "" Then
            Set NewEditRange = Application.Union(NewEditRange, CurrentCell)
        End If
        If CurrentCell.Value = "0" Then
            Set NewEditRange = Application.Union(NewEditRange, CurrentCell)
        End If
    Next
    ThisSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="New Edit Range", Range:=NewEditRange
    ThisSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

I expect this to unlock the sheet, delete all AllowEditRange objects, then add every blank cell in the table to the NewEditRange, then make a new AllowEditRange containing NewEditRange, then protect the sheet.
Instead it makes an AllowEditRange with the cells through row 14 or so, and I can still edit cells that are not in that range.

Comment: Where did you define CurrentEditRange and CurrentCell?

Comment: I defined them implicitly in the For loops.

Comment: @JolnarIndustries Picky, but should it read `For Each CurrentCell In DataTable.Cells` instead?  (I *believe* that `.Cells` is the implicit default, but you can also have `.Rows`, `.Columns`, `.Areas`, et cetera)  More to the point, should you be using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`?  And you only need 1 `If` statement: `If CurrentCell.Value = "" OR CurrentCell.Value = "0" Then`

Comment: Is the Worksheet actually Protected if you run this code?  If you step through line-by-line with F8, does it do anything unexpected?

Comment: Everything outside the table is protected just fine.  I haven't tried going through step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out the problem is that you can't protect cells in tables.  Period.  If you are interested in them adding this feature, go to https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/16452913-get-tables-working-on-protected-sheets-add-rows and vote.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `Option Explicit
I have some doubt that Application.Union works on NewEditRange if it is still nothing. You should initialize it and may have to split the case of NewEditRange being nothing or not.

(Can't comment due to rep)

Comment: So maybe just add Set NewEditRange = Range($A$1) or something like that after the Dim?

Comment: Set NewEditRange = Nothing

Comment: Ups, too hastily: Of course then you Need to distinguish `if NewEditRange is nothing then ... else ... end if.